# Invalid operands to binary - (have 'int' and 'int *')

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I've a problem when I run the program which is:

> invalid operands to binary - (have 'int' and 'int *')

Since I defined a dynamic array `**engelCikacagiYer` then I tried to make an operation on `karakterHP`

```
int karakterHP = 100;

int **engelCikacagiYer;

engelCikacagiYer = malloc(engelSayisi * sizeof(int));

for(i = 0; i < engelSayisi; i++){
    engelCikacagiYer[i] = (rand() % (100 - 5 + 1) + 5);
}

for(i = parkurUzunlugu.Baslangic; i < parkurUzunlugu.Bitis; i++){
    if (asal(engelCikacagiYer)) {
        karakterHP -= engelCikacagiYer[i];
        printf("%d\t", karakterHP);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably sufficient to remove one `*` from the declaration of `engelCikacagiYer`.

Comment: Probably, the first `for` loop is the issue. But, assuming you get past that, `engelCikacagiYer` is function scoped, but in the second `for` loop, you're using `engeller.engelCikacagiYer`. There's no [posted] code that associates (e.g. assigns to/from) the two variables. So, how is the `struct` element variable initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code:

```
int **engelCikacagiYer;

engelCikacagiYer = malloc(engelSayisi*sizeof(int));
```

Is not correct, to allocate memory to a double pointer, aka pointer to pointer you need to allocate using the size it points to and that is pointer to `int` so you would need:

```
engelCikacagiYer = malloc(engelSayisi*sizeof(int*));
```

Or better yet:

```
engelCikacagiYer = malloc(engelSayisi*sizeof(*engelCikacagiYer));
```

Later you try to assign an `int` value to a `engelCikacagiYer[i]` which is a pointer variable not an `int` variable, hence the error.

If you really need a double pointer, after the first `malloc` you will need to allocate memory for each `engelCikacagiYer[i]` pointer:

```
for(int i = 0; i < engelSayisi; i++){
    engelCikacagiYer[i] = malloc(sizeof(**engelCikacagiYer));
}
```

And assing values as if it was a 2D array (I mean using the same notation), example:

```
engelCikacagiYer[i][0] = (rand()%(100-5+1)+5);
```

or

```
*engelCikacagiYer[i] = (rand()%(100-5+1)+5);
```

Here is a simplified possible implementation of a correct allocation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int **engelCikacagiYer;

    engelCikacagiYer = malloc(100 * sizeof(*engelCikacagiYer)); //check allocation for errors

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        engelCikacagiYer[i] = malloc(sizeof(**engelCikacagiYer)); //check allocation
        *engelCikacagiYer[i] = (rand() % (100 - 5 + 1) + 5);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) //test print
    {
        printf("%d ", *engelCikacagiYer[i]);
    }
}
```

In any case, for the code you present using a single pointer to `int` would also be a valid (and simpler) solution.

Comment: All true, and upvoted, but I suspect that the OP may actually have wanted an `int *` instead of an `int **`.  That would lead to a somewhat simpler solution with fewer changes from the original code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, now that you mention it, it's likely he does, I hope not though :)

Answer (score 2):

Change `int **engelCikacagiYer;` to `int *engelCikacagiYer;`.

By your code it seems you want a dynamic array of ints, not a dynamic array of int pointers.